# Is it possible to attach a MDF file to an Azure SQL database?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have just created an Azure Website and Linked SQL Database.

I have a SQL Server 2008 SP2 database on my local machine. Is it possible to detach the local `.mdf` file, FTP it to Azure and then attach it as a SQL database in Azure? The only other way is to export the scheme and load this, followed by the data.

In the absence of detaching and attaching DBs, I have come across "SQLAzureMW" which looks very useful in guiding me through this process.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry my fault, a typo... I meant ".mdf".

Comment: Have a look at this tool.

SQL Database Migration Wizard v3.9.14 & v4.0.17

http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/

Comment: @KennethM.Nielsen unfortunately that fantastic tool doesn't work with mdf files. Useless comment

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can deploy an database from Management studio to Azure.

[image: Just use this wizard]

Comment: Kenneth, thank you for this. What version are you using. I have to admit I am on 2008 sp2 Management Studio, and I do not see your Azure options.

Comment: Just download the latest management studio from Microsoft, i'm on sql 2012

Comment: Kenneth, I have been playing around with MS's SSDT schema and Data compare tool from within VS2012. It is good. So this is another option. I will try yours as well. Many thanks.

Comment: Is it also possible to migrate an older version of `.mdf` file using a newer version of SSMS?