# Uploading database to Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I need to upload an MDF file to Azure SQL. According to [Is it possible to attach a MDF file to an Azure SQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20814658/is-it-possible-to-attach-a-mdf-file-to-an-azure-sql-database) the correct way to do this is to import the MDF to SQL Server Management Studio and then right click and export it to Azure SQL.

However all I'm getting is an error claiming that:
[image]

I have no idea what this **actually** means nor why I am unable to upload the database to Azure. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In order to import a Database to Azure, you will need to create a BACPAC file. Instructions can be found in this [MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brunoterkaly/archive/2013/09/26/how-to-export-an-on-premises-sql-server-database-to-windows-azure-storage.aspx).

And just in case you run into it, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847189/sql-azure-bacpac-local-restore) has some good links for where to get the SQL Server Data Tools required to import a BACPAC from Azure. You probably need to get those installed before being able to export to BACPAC.

Update: Adding this so you can see my export options:
[image]

Comment: I've followed that and it makes a "dacpac" file which I guess is different from a bacpac file. Microsoft sure make this process stupidly complex.

Comment: Also a dacpack contains no table data. Are they even trying to help their users out?

Comment: Looking in my management studio, I have two options that are similar yet different. Try using the Tasks -> Export Data Tier Application as it will create a BACPAC instead of the DACPAC from the "Extract" operation.

Comment: I have SQL Server Management Studio 2014, with MS Data Access Components (MDAC) 6.3.9600.17415

Answer (score 0):

This message means that you will need to create a Windows VM within Azure that has a full install of SQL Server on it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj823132.aspx

Comment: So what good is Azure SQL? I'm not currently looking to run a full VM. All I'm needing is a Web App (ASP.NET) and a database via Azure SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using this tool.
http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/
It will generate the script from your local database and execute it on Azure Sql.